# How Do You See If an Invoke-WebRequest Download Was Succesful in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have the following:

```
$variable = Invoke-WebRequest https://path/to/file -OutFile c:\download-directory\
Write-Host $variable
```

I would like to see if the `Invoke-WebRequest` download is successful.  The above `Write-Host` returns nothing.  How do I get the result status of the download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `-OutFile` seems to mess with the pipeline. Add the `-PassThru` parameter to populate your variable as well as getting the results to file

```powershell
$variable = Invoke-WebRequest https://path/to/file -OutFile c:\download-directory\ -PassThru
Write-Host $variable.StatusCode
```

Comment: Would `Tee-Object` also be a fit for this?

Comment: @Matt Not really. The `-OutFile` parameter only writes the *content* to the file, `Tee-Object` will write the entire object. Most of the time you'd only be interested in the data returned from the service, not the metadata.